# Jarvis march best case vs convex hull lower bound

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, convex-hull

We know the convex hull has a lower bound of (n log n) whereas the best case complexity of Jarvis march algorithm is O(n). Are these results contradicting?

Comment: Doesn't the *Jarvis march algorithm* has *O(n h)* worst case time complexity with *h* the number of elements on the convex hull?

Comment: yes but I need to know if the lower bound of convex hull is contradicting the best case of jarvis march and why ? and also the worse case complexity of jarvis march id O(n^2).

Comment: it is not, since you say that the *best* case is *O(n)*, and that is true. One can be lucky that the convex hull for example has three points, and that we thus only need to do three "scans". That does not say much about the worst case however.

Comment: But convex hull algorithm has lower bound of nlogn and jarvis march is also a convex hull algorithm so why the difference in lower bound

Comment: because the lower bound is defined over the entire "problem space", not over some lucky instances.

Comment: please can you elaborate since lower bound is supposed to be minimum number of steps

Comment: no, the lower bound means that the "theoretical best worst-case performance" is *O(n log n)*. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/lower-bound-for-convex-hull

Comment: So we can say the lower bound gives the best worst-case performance on a typical or random input of size n whereas the best case is one instance of the algorithm of the input size n when the input is such that the algorithm yields the result with least number of steps over all instances of input of size n.